# BASH ,"touch" and "ln-s" inside for loop

Tags: bash, for-loop, syntax, touch

while running this code , I get this error:

syntax error near unexpected token `('`     touch FILE$i FILE($i+1);'

what is wrong ?

```
#!/bin/bash

  for ((i=1; i<=99; i++ ));
    do        
    touch FILE$i FILE($i+1);
    ln -s FILE$i FILE($i+1);
       
     done
```

Comment: Off-topic: When you are going to `ln -s FILE 1 FILE2`, you do not need to touch FILE2 first. Your code is trying to make a chain of symbolic links. Are you sure you want that, or do want FILE2,..,FILE99 all linked to FILE1. In that case you might want `touch FILE1; for ((i=2;i<=99;i++));do ln -s FILE$i; done`.

Answer (score 1):

To do arithmetic, use the `$((...))` syntax:

```sh
    touch FILE$i FILE$(($i+1))
```

See https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Arithmetic-Expansion